# Code difference between the two times

Tags: time, vb6

I need help with code vb6
I need code like this

```
t1.text=now ' example "10:30:00 PM"
t2.text="1:00:00 am"  ' that next day and i can chang him
t3.text=t2.text-t1.text ' he most be "2:30:00"and Countdown
'and i need code to + hour amd minute 
' example 
't2.text is "1:00:00" + new time  "1:30:00" = "2:30:00"
't3.text most be "3:00:00" and Countdown
```

Can help me plz thx

**[EDIT]**

i try this code but dont work good 
Because time text3 this day and text4 next day

```css
Dim timein As Date
Dim timeout As Date
Dim v_diff As Date

Private Sub Timer3_Timer()
text4.text="1:00:00am"
Text3.Text = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS AMPM")
timein = Text4.Text
timeout = Text3.Text
v_diff = (timein - timeout)
'*********************************************
Hourdiff = Hour(v_diff)
minutediff = Minute(v_diff)
seconddiff = Second(v_diff)
'*********************************************
Text5.Text = Hourdiff & " : " & minutediff & " : " & seconddiff
Label2.Caption = Text5.Text
```

Comment: Don't try at add String values, it has numerous issues.  You can't add two times and expect get a new time anyway.  You must add an *interval* to a time, using something like the `DateAdd()` function.  Run, don't wak, to read the manual.

Comment: I wrote code to illustrate the idea that I want Is You can write full source code for I do not know the right formula for that
Thank you
Note: Google Translate, my English is weak

Comment: look to this  pic plz  http://filaty.com/Dvw  i need full source code its eazy to u thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are no numbers, you cannot add or substract them. You need to convert them to numbers or dates first before you can add/substract them

To add/substract dates you can best use thje DateAdd() and DateDiff() functions

To repeatedly check for something, you can best use a Timer control

Have a look at the following test project:

```
'1 form with
'  1 textbox        : name=Text1
'  1 textbox        : name=Text2
'  1 label          : name=Label1
'  1 command button : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  'show difference between text1 and text2
  ShowDiff Text1.Text, Text2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  'show countdown from now till text2
  ShowDiff CStr(Now), Text2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'load some values
  Text1.Text = CStr(Now)
  Text2.Text = CStr(DateAdd("d", 1, Now))
  'configure timer to show difference every second
  With Timer1
    .Interval = 1000
    .Enabled = True
  End With 'Timer1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 4
  Text1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Text2.Move 0, sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Label1.Move 0, 2 * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Command1.Move 0, 3 * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
End Sub

Private Sub ShowDiff(strStart As String, strEnd As String)
  Dim datStart As Date, datEnd As Date
  Dim lngMin As Long
  Dim strDiff As String
  'convert strings to date types
  datStart = CDate(strStart)
  datEnd = CDate(strEnd)
  'calculate difference in minutes
  lngMin = DateDiff("n", datStart, datEnd)
  'hours
  strDiff = CStr(lngMin \ 60)
  'minutes
  strDiff = strDiff & ":" & Right$("0" & CStr(lngMin Mod 60), 2)
  'show difference as hours:minutes
  Label1.Caption = strDiff
End Sub
```

It will start with the current time in Text1, and extactly the same time tomorrow in Text2

When you click on the button, the difference between Text1 and Text2 will show in Label1 .. this will always be 24:00 at the start, but you can change Text1 and Text2 to get other results

Every second the Timer will process its event, and this will show the countdown from the current time to the time in Text2 .. every second this will overwrite anything that is shown in Label1

Comment: thx that is it but i need 1 more code   plz  in this code:  Text2.Text = CStr(DateAdd("d", 1, Now))  how can add more hour and minutes

Comment: i use thes :  Text2.Text = CStr(DateAdd("d", 1, "2:30:00"))   i get this :           text2.text =31/12/1899 02:30:00 am

Comment: what do you want to do in Text2 ? ... for more info about DateAdd put your cursor on it, and press F1

Comment: to do that : either split text2 into 2 labels (1 showing hours, 1 showing minutes) or store the hours and minutes into variables to show later in text2 ... then add 4 buttons to increase or decrease those values ... that shouldnt be too hard, please try and ask again if you fail

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262712%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function.
You also want to be storing values in variables declared using `dim variableName as Date`, not text boxes. You'll also want to sanitize the input somehow, so that your program doesn't crash the first time someone enters "bob" as a time.

Comment: I wrote code to illustrate the idea that I want Is You can write full source code for I do not know the right formula for that
Thank you
Note: Google Translate, my English is weak

Comment: Hrqls has now given you a much better answer - I won't expand further on this one.